# I have a problem in the gradient overlay

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

When i use the gradient overlay in PS CS6, the gradient only effects one side of the sentence, sometimes doesn't make any change in it (the picture).

[image: The picture]

Comment: I think at the very least you need to take a screenshot with the *effect visibility ON* so anyone can see what you are referring to. Your current screenshot has visibility off for the effects/layer styles.

Answer (score 1):

Your effect layer is switched off.
[image]